# How to show record with multiple children WPF DataGrid?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid

I have a list of Customer objects which I want to show in a DataGrid. I've bound the List via code behind:

```
dataGrid.DataContext = customers;
```

Each customer has one or more phone numbers. I would like to list them in the row/record of the customer. How do I go about doing this?
My DataGrid looks like this in XAML:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="212" IsReadOnly="True"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,41,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding}"   
    Name="dataGrid" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="932">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=LastName}" Header="Porting ID"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=FirstName}" Header="Operator" />
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The Customer class is:

```
public class Customer
{
  public String LastName { get; set; }
  public String FirstName { get; set; }
  public List<Phonenumber> PhoneNumbers { get; set; }
}
```

The PhoneNumber class is:

```
public class PhoneNumber
{
  public String AreaCode {get;set;}
  public String Number {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

first pls set the itemssource to customers not the datacontext. now to your question: you could use a DataGridTemplateColumn and bind to your phonenumbers collection. the datatemplate for this template column could be a simple itemscontrol.

EDIT:

```
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Phonenumbers">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Phonenumbers}">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding AreaCode}" Margin="0,0,5,0"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Number}"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

ps: i will update the template if you post your code ;)

Comment: if you post your customer Phonenumber code, i will add an example

Comment: check my updated original post. As you can see it has 2 members: area code and (subscriber) number.

Comment: thx for downvote a working example without a comment! @Henri i update my code to your requirements

Comment: Thanks, this worked! (as to why someone would downvote my question, I have no clue). No to HOW this works: where do I get the theory behind this? I'm rather clueless about WPF still, especially the whole binding thing (I used to work a lot with Rails, where there's no such thing as 'binding to Grids')

Comment: just start reading about wpf and binding in codeproject or other blogposts. a simple answer would be on the one hand you have an object/class/viewmodel where you define properties!(that should be the first step every time,see MVVM viewmodel first :)) on the other hand you have your view/usercontrols where you wanna bind your properties to. there for you need the right DATACONTEXT and then of course the binding. the vs output window and tools like Snoop are your friend when looking for binding errors. at least just ask a question here, you will get your answer ;)